# How to print extracted dictionary values in input fields of html (placeholder)

Tags: python, html, django

I am quite new to django and struggling to do something very simple.I am working on django based pdf data extraction project.in this project i am taking invoice pdf from user and then extracting fields like issuer, invoice_number, date, amount, currency, other.and then save those data into database.everything works fine but the only thing is i want to print extracted data in html forms input fields.guys could you please help me

this is the flow

input invoice.pdf --> extract button --> print values in inputs fields of html form --> submit

after pdf extraction i got this dictionary

```
{'issuer': 'Freefiber', 'amount': 29.99, 'date': '02/07/2015', 'invoice_number': '562044387', 'currency': 'EUR', 'other': {'amount_untaxed': 24.99, 'date_due': '02/08/2015', 'vat': 'FR60421938861', 'line_number': 'FO10479674', 'client_id': '10577874', 'desc': 'Invoice from Free'}}
```

expected output
[image]

here is my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from .models import InvoiceList
import os
from .forms import browse
from .models import handle_uploaded_file 
from invoice2data import extract_data

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    invoices = InvoiceList.objects.all()
    context = {
        'invoices': invoices,
    }
    return (render(request, 'index.html', context))

def create(request):
    print(request.POST)
    issuer = request.GET['issuer']
    invoice_number = request.GET['invoice_number']
    date = request.GET['date']
    amount = request.GET['amount']
    currency = request.GET['currency']
    other = request.GET['other']
    invoice_details = InvoiceList(issuer=issuer, invoice_number=invoice_number, date=date,amount=amount,currency=currency,other=other)
    invoice_details.save()
    return redirect('/')

file_list = os.listdir("extraction/static/upload")
def add_invoice(request):
    result = None
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = browse(request.POST, request.FILES)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file']) # store file in upload folder
            path = "pdfextractor/static/upload/"+ str(request.FILES['file'])#path of selected file
            result1 = extract_data(path) # extract data from invoice pdf file
            listl=['issuer','invoice_number','date','amount','currency']
            new_in_dict={}
            c={}
            for key in result1:
                if key in listl:
                    new_in_dict[key]=result1[key]
                else:
                    c[key]=result1[key]

            new_in_dict['other']=c
            result = new_in_dict # this is final dictionary

    else:
        form = browse()
    context = {"form": form, "result": result}
    return render(request,'add_invoice.html', context)
    #return render(request, 'add_invoice.html')



def delete(request, id):
    invoices = InvoiceList.objects.get(pk=id)
    invoices.delete()
    return redirect('/')

def edit(request, id):
    invoices = InvoiceList.objects.get(pk=id)
    context = {
        'invoices': invoices
    }
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)


def update(request, id):
    invoices = InvoiceList.objects.get(pk=id)

    invoices.issuer = request.GET['issuer']
    invoices.invoice_number = request.GET['invoice_number']
    invoices.date = request.GET['date']
    invoices.amount = request.GET['amount']
    invoices.currency = request.GET['currency']
    invoices.other = request.GET['other']
    invoices.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

add_invoice.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="small_div">
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h2>Invoices List</h2>
    <hr>
    
    <form action="/create">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="Submit" name="extract" value="extract"/>
            <br>
            <label class="form-group" for="issuer">issuer: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="issuer"><br>

            <label class="form-group" for="invoice_number">invoice_number: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="invoice_number"><br>

            <label class="form-group" for="date">date: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date"><br>

            <label class="form-group" for="amount">amount: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amount"><br>

            <label class="form-group" for="currency">currency: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="currency"><br>

            <label class="form-group" for="other">other: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="other"><br>

            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="save">

        </form>
        <br>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also upload your pdf sample file for testing ?

Comment: Hey lostin you no need to worry about data extraction part that part is working but if you still wanted to then here are some pdf invoices formats https://github.com/MayurSatav/invoice-auditing-system-using-django/tree/master/pdfextractor/static/upload